# Why am I getting an "ambiguous column name" error in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I can't quite figure out why I'm getting the error. The call worked fine until I added the second where clause.

```
ambiguous column name: nanoProd.name: 
SELECT 
nanoProd.name AS prodName,
nanoProd.intro AS prodIntro,
nanoProd.prodText AS nanoText, 
nanoFiles.fileLoc AS nanoFile 
FROM nanoProd 
LEFT JOIN nanoRelFiles on nanoFiles.rid = nanoRelFiles.file_id 
LEFT JOIN nanoProd on nanoProd.rid = nanoRelFiles.item_id 
WHERE nanoRelFiles.scr_type = 'prod' AND nanoRelFiles.fileUse = 'list'
```

Comment: `nanoProd` is used twice. Hence you have to use an alias for each one of the instances of the table used in the query. Then specify the alias in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: that solved the issue but now I'm being told `no such column: nanoFiles.fileLoc` when I know it's there.

Comment: taking out `nanoFiles.fileLoc AS nanoFile ` errors saying that nanoFiles.rid isn't a column either...

Comment: nanoFiles isn't one of the tables in your FROM